# More efficient way to loop through an object

Tags: php, object

There's a part in my page where you can add, edit or delete school details, and it wasn't supposed to save entries to the database until the user hits <kbd>Enter</kbd>, so I save all data in an object first.

My object looks like this:

```
schooldetails : {
  "1": {
    "school_ctr":"schoolctr_1",
    "school":"Fiat Lux Academe",
    "course":"",
    "qualification":"High School",
    "date_grad":"06/04/2008",
    "notes":"*graduated with honors",
    "deleted":0
  },
  "2": {
    "school_ctr":"schoolctr_2",
    "school":"College of St. Benilde",
    "course":"Computer Science",
    "qualification":"Bachelor / College",
    "date_grad":"06/05/2012",
    "notes":"",
    "deleted":0
  },
  "3":{
    "school_ctr":"schoolctr_3",
    "school":"Siliman University",
    "course":"Information Technology",
    "qualification":"Post Graduate / Master",
    "date_grad":"06/06/2014",
    "notes":"",
    "deleted":0
  }
}
```

I passed it through AJAX and I was able to save info through this code:

```
if(!empty($school_details_new)){
  foreach($school_details_new as $key => $value) {
    foreach($value as $school_data => $data_values) {
      if($school_data == "school")
        $s_name = mysql_real_escape_string($data_values);
      if($school_data == "course")
        $s_degree = mysql_real_escape_string($data_values);
      if($school_data == "qualification")
        $s_type = mysql_real_escape_string($data_values);
      if($school_data == "date_grad")
        $s_enddate = mysql_real_escape_string($data_values);
      if($school_data == "notes")
        $s_notes = mysql_real_escape_string($data_values);                      
    }
  $sql = "INSERT INTO `SchoolDetails` (`personID`, `School`, `Type`, `End_Date`, `Degree`, `Notes`) VALUES ($id, '$s_name', '$s_type', '$s_enddate', '$s_degree', '$s_notes');";
  $res_sql = mysql_query ($sql);
  }
}
```

This is actually working fine with me.  I don't have any errors or anything but I do believe there is a more efficient way to do this without having a lot of `if` statements. Thoughts?

Answer (score 7):

Indeed there is! Use **[prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)** instead of manually escaping and inserting into your query!

> [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new
>   code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are
>   officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red
>   box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared
>   statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use
>   [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this
>   article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose
>   PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

```
//mysqli connection somewhere around here...

if (!empty($school_details_new)) {
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, "INSERT INTO `SchoolDetails` (`personID`, `School`, `Type`, `End_Date`, `Degree`, `Notes`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
    foreach ($school_details as $school) {
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "isssss", $id, $school["school"], $school["qualification"], $school["date_grad"], $school["course"], $school["notes"]);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for being the first to jump on this, +1 to reiterate the depreciation of mysql_*.